# Firebase suddenly showing certificate to web.app and some random site

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Our website was up and running normally.

Today suddenly the domain started showing invalid cerificate signed to web.app.

And the www domain certificate is working, but it's showing that it's given to some random website [www.flatmatecafe.com](http://www.flatmatecafe.com)

Anyone had this issue before? I tried to delete and create the domain again with new DNS settings, but still the same issue.

Comment: It sounds like your site has not propagated on the shared certificate yet. This should normally only happen when you first configure the site in Firebase Hosting. If it happens after that, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes it happened on its own. The site was already up and running before. I sent a ticket thank you. :)